# JavaFX MediaView in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I have tried to create a MediaView in my fxml but it does not seem to work and just brings up errors. The video I am playing is based locally.

```
<MediaView>
   <MediaPlayer>
      <Media source="vid/video.avi"/>
   </MediaPlayer>
</MediaView>
```

Comment: What errors does it "bring up"?

Comment: "MediaPlayer is not a valid type" (javfx.fxml.LoadException)

Comment: Can you show your imports?

Comment: <?javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>                                                             <?javafx.scene.media.Media?>                                                                       I don't seem to have one for mediaplayer but it isn't showing any errors util I run it

Comment: mediaPlayer is also just a mediaView method so it is contained in <?javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>

Comment: The `<MediaPlayer>...` element instructs the `FXMLLoader` to instantiate the `MediaPlayer` class, so you need that import too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your FXML code, I get this warnings:

> Class javafx.scene.media.MediaView has no default property. Place javafx.scene.media.MediaView content in a proper element.
>
> Class javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer has no default property. Place javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer content in a proper element.

If you edit your FXML file on NetBeans, when you start adding `<MediaView>`, click Ctrl+space, and from all the properties, select `mediaPlayer`. Then Ctrl+space again, and select `MediaPlayer`. Now add `media`, and finally `Media`.

This is how it should look like:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <MediaView >
            <mediaPlayer>
                <MediaPlayer autoPlay="true">
                    <media>
                        <Media source="http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv" />
                    </media>
                </MediaPlayer>
            </mediaPlayer>    
        </MediaView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Note that `mediaPlayer` is a property of `MediaView`:

```
private ObjectProperty<MediaPlayer> mediaPlayer;
```

while `media` is a named argument of `MediaPlayer`:

```
public MediaPlayer(@NamedArg("media") Media media)
```

Comment: I did this but it is still giving me a Load Exception for <Media source="vid/video1.avi"/>

Comment: I fixed that. Just needed to make it "@vid/video1.avi"